# How to add a column on a shapefile in GRASS GIS

Tags: shapefile, grass-gis

I'm relatively new in GRASS GIS and I want to add a column to a shapefile.

I use GRASS GIS (version 7.8.6 on Ubuntu 20.04 .4 LTS), not the GRASS extension in QGIS.

I'm using the shapefile of the biogeographical realms. In this file the realms are identified by a string in the column REALM. I would like to assign a number to the corresponding string in a new column named REALM_ID.

What I want is something like that:

| REALM | REALM_ID |
| --- | --- |
| PA | 1 |
| NT | 2 |
| PA | 1 |
| NA | 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy to add a column. The GRASS module is `v.db.addcolumn`. The tricky part in your question is creating numbers for each **unique** value of REALM. Here's how I would do it:
(Let's say you have a GRASS vector called "bio_realms" and you're working in a Linux environment)

```
#First get a list of the unique values in the existing REALM column
realm_list=`db.select "SELECT DISTINCT REALM FROM bio_realms;"`
# Create the new column
v.db.addcolumn bio_realms column="realm_id INTEGER" 
# Now loop through all realms and update the new column,
# but keep a counter for the realm_id value
i=0
for r in $realm_list; do i=$((i+1)); v.db.update bio_realms column=realm_id value=$i where="REALM == '${r}'"; done
```

That should do it. If you're on some other operating system, you'll have to adapt the variables and looping appropriately.